# Neo4J ERROR: 'RULE planner does not support calling procedures'

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following cypher query:

```
UNWIND {venues} AS venue
MERGE (v:Venue {
    name: venue.name,
    id: venue.id, 
    formattedAddress: venue.formattedAddress, 
    latitude: venue.latitude, 
    longitude: venue.longitude 
})

WITH collect(v) AS markers, venue, v
CALL spatial.addNodes('venues', markers) YIELD count

WITH venue, v
UNWIND venue.cats as type
MERGE (ty:Type { name: type.shortName, id: type.id })
CREATE UNIQUE (v)-[:is]->(ty)
```

Yet I'm getting the following error:

> RULE planner does not support calling procedures

Comment: Something in your query is causing the RULE planner to be used instead of the COST planner. Maybe try changing `CREATE UNIQUE` into a `MERGE`? If that doesn't change it, try prepending the query with `CYPHER planner = COST` to force the planner type.

Comment: It's also a good idea to only MERGE using the unique id or index (such as :Venue(id) and :Type(id)), then use `ON CREATE SET ...` to set the rest of the properties, but only when this resulted in node creation.